# создание asp.net в C# с использованием mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

Здравствуйте. пытаю в VS15 работать с mongoDB, для этого скачал MongoDB.Driver версии 2.4.0. Также я использую GridFS. Также скачал последнюю версию из Nuget.

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;
using System.Configuration;

namespace _13.Models
{
    public class ComputerContext
    {
    MongoClient client;
    IMongoDatabase database;
    MongoGridFS gridFS;

    public ComputerContext()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDb"].ConnectionString;
        var con = new MongoUrlBuilder(connectionString);

        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        database = client.GetDatabase(con.DatabaseName);
        gridFS = new MongoGridFS(
            new MongoServer(
                new MongoServerSettings { Server = con.Server }),
            con.DatabaseName,
            new MongoGridFSSettings()
        );
    }

    public IMongoCollection<Computer> Computers
    {
        get { return database.GetCollection<Computer>("Computers"); }
    }

    public MongoGridFS GridFS
    {
        get { return gridFS; }
    }
}
}
```

Но проблема в том, что не выполняется подключение пространства имен GridFS и, соответственно, на все что с ним связано компилятор ругается.
Пытаюсь делать по примеру отсюда [Описание работы с GridFS](http://metanit.com/nosql/mongodb/4.12.php)

Comment: Привет, столкнулся с этой же проблемой. Может, ты уже нашел решение?

Comment: Пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver.GridFS/ установлен?

Comment: @Mike111 создайте новый вопрос

Comment: @Mike111 извини, что так поздно отвечаю. У меня не было уже времени разбираться с этим, но как я понял нужно читать документацию т.к. технология еще развивается и там много чего меняют